# How to use tf.Session().reset()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

How to use `tf.Session().reset()` ? and is there any relation between it and `tf.Session().close()` ?

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(something)
   """what is the actual syntax to use sess.reset() and how does it compare to sess.close()"""
   sess.reset()
```

Answer (score 1):

`sess.close()` is used to free all resources associated/allocated by the session. For instance, free up GPU memory and RAM.

`sess.reset()` does the similar job, but is tailored for distributed environment. It is supposed to be called on a distributed session to stop all jobs in a distributed workload.

[Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The syntax and distributed training in TF changed drastically since I used it last time.

Comment: Okay, Then do you know any method to reset specific tensors in the graph

Comment: sort of. if your tensor is a variable (because if it is an add operation than there is nothing to reset) than you can assign zeros to it, for instance

Comment: is thete any default function in TF to do that

Comment: still not the answer I was looking for ,but thanks anyway

Comment: "'sess.close()' is used to free all resources associated/allocated by the session. For instance, free up GPU memory and RAM" FYI, it would make sense for it to free GPU memory, but it does not. Example issues https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15880